# How to select all the rows where cells in a column has a specific value?

Tags: excel, vba

Everybody.

I built the following table as a sample because I'm trying to do a vba code that can select the rows based in the values from the column "Date". For example, all rows with the value 01/04/2022 should be selected in the end of the code.

| Name | Specialization | Born | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Engineering | Brazil | mar/2022 |
| Paul | Administrator | USA | mar/2022 |
| Mary | Lawyer | India | mar/2022 |
| Carl | Receptionist | Canada | mar/2022 |
| Kelly | Singer | Singapore | mar/2022 |
| Michael | Seller | Portugal | apr/2022 |
| Newton | Programmer | Japan | apr/2022 |
| Kevin | Designer | Korea | apr/2022 |

I can't use AutoFilter function, because some columns are from a external source, so Excel won't allow me to use it. Other thing is the format I'm using for the date. Here in my country the standard is dd/mm/yyyy.

I tried to solve this problem with the following code:

```
Sub test()
Dim c As Range, FoundCells As Range
Dim firstaddress As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets("Test")
    'find first cell that contains what you want to find
    Set c = .Cells.Find(What:="01/04/2022", After:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
  
    'if the search returns a cell
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        'note the address of first cell found
        firstaddress = c.Address
        Do
            'FoundCells is the variable that will refer to all of the
            'cells that are returned in the search
            If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
                Set FoundCells = c
            Else
                Set FoundCells = Union(c, FoundCells)
            End If
            'find the next instance of "rec"
            Set c = .Cells.FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And firstaddress <> c.Address
              
        'after entire sheet searched, select all found cells
        FoundCells.Select
    Else
        'if no cells were found in search, display msg
        MsgBox "No cells found."
    End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But it isn't working properly. It never find the cells. I don't know why..

Could somebody help me, please?

Att,

Paulo

Comment: Per your example data it is not clear if you really have dates in your file. Do you really yhave dates in your file and is it always the first of a month?

Comment: @Storax Hello. I really have dates in the last column in my excel file. They are in dd/mm/yyyy format and always the first day of the month, but formatted to show as mmm/yyyy.

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change only one line

```
Set c = .Cells.Find(What:=#4/1/2022#, After:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
```

Putting the date into `# ...#` makes sure that VBA will recognise it as a date and setting `LookIn` to `xlFormulas` will make sure `Find` looks for a date.